# Disable Emacs mouse mode after exiting

Tags: emacs, iterm2

Recently, I noticed that if an ssh session in which I've been using Emacs times out, I can no longer scroll. Instead, any mouse input prints all sorts of strange character sequences on the screen (e.g. `R6a`, `Aa;`, etc.). The only way I can get it to stop is by entering and exiting Emacs on the local. Mouse input in Emacs is enabled on both remote and local computers.

Is there a nicer way to get mouse input to work again than just reentering and exiting Emacs?

Thanks!

Comment: Does typing `reset` in the terminal fix it?

Comment: Thank you; yes it does! That was actually really simple... I just haven't had to use `reset` in a while.